# In nuxt.js getting CORS problem No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: nuxt.js, laravel-8

I am doing authentication register in nuxt.js with laravel8 backend when submit its getting error like this...
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

how to solve this,

register.vue

```js
 methods: {
   onSubmit(){
     this.$axios.$post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api", {
       email: this.email,
       password: this.password,
       name: this.name,
       returnSecureToken: true,
     } ,
     ).then(result => {
       console.log(result)
     })
     .catch(e => console.log(e));
   }
  }
```

nuxtConfig.js

```js
modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/auth',
    '@nuxtjs/proxy'
  ],

  proxy: {
    '/api': {
      target: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
      changeOrigin: true,
      pathRewrite: { '^/api': '/' },
    },
  },
  // Axios module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-axios
  axios: {
    baseURL: "https://127.0.0.1:8000/api",
    proxy: true,
    credentials: false
  },
```

Comment: and also I added proxy then its coming same error. how can solve this issue thank you

Comment: CORS error should not be handled in front. You need to fix this in the backend. And for your proxy try this instead: ``pathRewrite: { '^/api': '' },``

Comment: thank you for replay @Mani Mirjavadi, I added proxy in my nuxtConfig file like pathRewrite: { '^/api': ' ' }  its did not worked for me any other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

In nuxt.config.js turn proxy: true and add proxy which will be used while calling like this:

```
axios: {
    proxy: true
  },
proxy: {
    "/api": "https://127.0.0.1:8000"
  },
```

Than while calling the API just use "/api" it will append the prefix

```
 methods: {
   onSubmit(){
     this.$axios.$post("/api", {
       email: this.email,
       password: this.password,
       name: this.name,
       returnSecureToken: true,
     } ,
     ).then(result => {
       console.log(result)
     })
     .catch(e => console.log(e));
   }
  }
```

[Nuxt Link](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options/#proxy)

Comment: thank you @vishal sagar, I modified my code what you are said above but its throwing error like  Error: Request failed with status code 504

Comment: and in my vs code...
 ERROR  [HPM] Error occurred while proxying request localhost:3000/api to https://127.0.0.1:8000/ [ECONNRESET] (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)

Comment: how to fix CORS issue in NUXT.js No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Comment: @Anil Kumar it is a gateway error please check your backend is receiving the request or not. Did you restart everything after you changed the config? Please create a repo to help you out more.

Comment: Thank you @vishal sagar  everything fine but problem happened at crome I solved this. I did enable this ---> chrome.exe --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="c:/ChromeDevSession"